# UseGoogleAuthentication force login session expiration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5's external authentication middleware UseGoogleAuthentication/UseExternalSignInCookie with GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions. Is there a way to force a user to have to re-authenticate with Google each time a user visits the site?

Presently, if the user is already logged into Google and they access the site they do not have to re-authenticate with Google. Ideally the cookie assigned would only be good for their current session on the site...

```
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var authOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();
    authOptions.ClientId = AppSettingsHelper.GoogleClientId;
    authOptions.ClientSecret = AppSettingsHelper.GoogleClientSecret;
    authOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/account/linklogincallback");

    foreach (var scope in AppSettingsHelper.GoogleOAuthScope)
    {
        authOptions.Scope.Add(scope);
    }
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(authOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);` with `app.UseCookieAuthentication(..)` and specify the `ExpireTimeSpan`. `UseExternalSignInCookie` is just a helper for the cookie authentication method that uses certain defaults.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
    SlidingExpiration = true,
    ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

Notice that we are using `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie` here instead of `ApplicationCookie`

Comment: That doesn't quite accomplish what I was looking for. What I need to do is expire the external auth providers cookie should the browser session end. For example, if I close my browser and go back to the site I should be required to log back in... Thoughts on that?

Comment: @Jason All you need to do in that case is specify `false` for `isPersistent` when the user signs in. `AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false}, identity);`